# Why is my JAVA GUI opening multiple windows?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt, frame

I'm new to GUI's so sorry if the error is really blatant.
I'm trying to create a simple window with a couple of buttons, but every time I run the code, it opens four windows instead of just one. Any help would be appreciated.

```
public class CISUC extends JFrame implements Serializable {

    //interface
    JFrame mainFrame;
    JPanel mainPanel;
    JButton createProject, manageProject,listActive, listUnfinished,listaFinished;



    public CISUC(){
        //interface
        mainFrame = new JFrame();
        mainFrame.setResizable(false);
        mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,3));

        createProject= new JButton("Create Project");
        mainPanel.add(createProject);



        manageProject = new JButton("Manage Project");
        mainPanel.add(manageProject);  

        listActive = new JButton("List Active Projects");
        mainPanel.add(listActive); 

        listUnfinished = new JButton("List Unfinished Projects");
        mainPanel.add(listUnfinished);

        listFinished = new JButton("Listar Finished");
        mainPanel.add(listFinished);
        mainFrame.setSize(800, 500);
        mainFrame.add(mainPanel);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);

    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
        CISUC cisuc = new CISUC();


    }
}
```

Comment: Why does `CISUC` extend `JFrame` and also create a new `JFrame` in its constructor?  Is it supposed to *have* a `JFrame` or *be* a `JFrame`?  It's really weird to see it try to do both.

Comment: That being said, when I run your code (after fixing the syntax errors), it just pops up one frame with 5 buttons. How, *exactly*, are you running your code?

Comment: @azurefrog I'm just pressing the Run button on NetBeans. I want it to BE a ```JFrame``` so I'll change the constructor to ```super``` call

Comment: I ran your code just now. It only opens one window. What is the issue here? One thing to note is that clicking on `X` on the window won't stop the application as you didn't handle it. So you need to manually kill it.

Comment: @SunilDabburi *"So you need to manually kill it."* No, wrong conclusion based on (correct observation) *"as you didn't handle it"*. To correctly handle it, sometimes it is as simple as calling [`setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultCloseOperation(int)).

Comment: @SunilDabburi is it your understanding that 'killed manually' is the same as setting a default close operation? Sidebar: `WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE` (different from the close operation I suggested) is closest to 'killing a frame manually'. If there are non-daemon threads running when a frame is disposed, the app. will **keep** running. Those threads should not just be killed with no further thought, and likely should be 'cleaned up' and shut down by the programmer. So I stick with my original advice. Your suggestion is potentially misleading, and as a result encouraging bad practices.

Answer (score 0):

As ohers already said to you, there is nothing wrong with the number of Frames opened, i just tried the code and it opens a single JFrame.

In my opinion there are a few mistakes in your code: you don't need to extend JFrame and implement serializable for this purpose... this way you are making your application heavier because of unused inherithed (unused) fields and methods from parent class. Moreover (as others already told you), there is no close operation linked to your JFrame, so when you press the X button your application just keep running until you shut down your computer.

To avoid this jut add the following statement:

```
mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

- I suggest you to put main method, main Object, and JPanel in separate
  classes, making your application easier to read, debug, and maintain. If you are planning to have many funcionalities it can be a good idea to have a custom class extending JFrame, where you can assemble different custom GUI objects, each one extending a Swing/AWT component.. and finally call them in you main object or directly in main class! There is no limit to this, but use inheritance wisely: many classes mean much more boilerplate code... there is always a tradeoff!
- Another great idea should be to put graphics initialization (size,
  colours, etc...) in a separate method outside from constructor. Just
  create something like `private void initializeGraphics(){...}
- Other to this, you can do the same when mapping actionListeners to
  buttons, putting them in separate named classes or at least in a
  separate method like `private void addListeners(){...}`, and just
  call this at the end of your constructor code.

I'm telling you this because when using Swing it's very easy to have something like 5000 lines of unreadable and unmaintainable code if you start adding everyting in the same place!

Good luck with your application :)

PS: take a look to MigLayout... i think you are going to like it, even it could seem a bit complicated at the beginning.